# how can i create a list from the lines read from a file in python with proper indexing

Tags: python, list, file-io, newline

here I am reading data from a file IPmarks.txt which contains roll no and marks in different assignments of a student in the format
**Rollno1,m1,m2,m3.......** eg:- 2021264,10,20,50,100
**Rollno2,m1,m2,m3.......** eg:- 2021265,9,11,39,97

I want to read these lines from the file and create a list containing all the elements with indexing 0,1,2..... and so on
at index 0 - Rollno1, at index 1 - m1 and so on

I have tried the below code but the problem is that it contains the elements in a list but when i do print(grade[0])it prints 2021264,10,20,50,100(first line of file) and print(grade[0][0]) prints 2(first character of rollno1) instead of complete **Rollno1 - 2021264**

the question should be solved without importing any modules, should be done simply by file i/o

```
f = open("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\python\\IPmarks.txt","r")
grades = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]
print(grades[0])
```

Comment: Your file looks like a CSV. There's a standard module for reading such things reliably https://pymotw.com/3/csv/index.html

Comment: i don't have to do it by importing any module. Simply by file I/O

Comment: If there are restrictions or limitations, they should be clearly given in the question itself. Please click [edit] and update it. Thank you.